# OWT iOS Video Streaming Issues: No Video with 5.1 rc1 & HD+ Resolution Freezing

Tags: ios, webrtc, video-streaming

I'm experiencing several issues with video streaming using the Open WebRTC Toolkit (OWT) on iOS, and I'm seeking anyone who might have encountered similar problems or could provide some assistance.

The first issue arose when streaming video at resolutions greater than HD using OWT version 5.0. I'm sending frames via `videoSource.capturer` instead of the default OWT camera. The stream looks fine on the iOS device itself, but freezes on the receiving end. This issue was detailed on [GitHub](https://github.com/open-webrtc-toolkit/owt-client-native/issues/724), but I have yet to find a resolution.

To attempt a workaround, I updated my OWT iOS client from version 5.0 (stable, released 14th April 2021) to version 5.1 rc1 (pre-release, released 7th April 2023). However, this led to a second, different issue.

After updating to 5.1 rc1, the audio streaming works as anticipated, but there's no video stream at all, irrespective of the resolution. This is a new issue that was not present in version 5.0.

Here are my questions:

- Has anyone else experienced these issues while using the OWT iOS
  client for video streaming, particularly when streaming HD+
  resolutions and sending frames via `videoSource.capturer`?
- Has anyone worked with OWT iOS version 5.1 rc1? Are there known
  issues related to video streaming with this version?
- Is there a specific version of the OWT server that is compatible with
  the OWT iOS 5.1 client?

Any insights, possible solutions, or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.